# Why won't this output all of my data from my MySQL Artist table?

Tags: php, mysql

I've written up a pretty simple query to output all the data from the Artist table and output them in the established tables. I've double checked the database and all the spelling is correct, but I'm not getting any data being outputted for some reason.

Connector Code

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "b4014107", "Windows1", "b4014107_db2") or die (mysqli_connect_error());

?>
```

Main Code

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>View Artist Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//Includes speicifed details in order to connect to MySQL
include('ConnectorCode.php');

//mysql_query command is used to select data from Artist table
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_Artist");

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Artist ID</th> <th>Artist Name</th> </tr>";

//Results are looped and then displayed in tables
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['Artist_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['Artist_Name'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

//Connection is closed
      mysqli_close($conn);


 ?>

<p><a href="ArtistNew.php">Add a new Artist</a></p>
<p><a href="ArtistEdit.php">Edit a current Artist</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. Do you get any warnings?

Comment: Give the connector file without your data please.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I've added the connector file into the page

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs. Never assume your queries are working.

Comment: can you see the headings of your table?

Comment: `code` Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME1/7/b4014107/public_html/Admin_Artist_Page.php on line 16 Call Stack: 0.0024 639648 1. {main}() /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME1/7/b4014107/public_html/Admin_Artist_Page.php:0 0.0039 643112 2. mysqli_query() /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME1/7/b4014107/public_html/Admin_Artist_Page.php:16 `code`

Comment: `code` mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME1/7/b4014107/public_html/Admin_Artist_Page.php on line 22 Call Stack: 0.0024 639648 1. {main}() /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME1/7/b4014107/public_html/Admin_Artist_Page.php:0 0.0041 643160 2. mysqli_fetch_array() /studenthome.hallam.shu.ac.uk/STUDENTHOME1/7/b4014107/public_html/Admin_Artist_Page.php:22  `code`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

Use: `$result->fetch_assoc()`

Instead of: `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I just need to add $conn within the mysqli_query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_Artist");
```